# Ни с одного браузера не скачивается файл

Tags: windows, webbrowser, download

Знаю, это напрямую не связано с программированием, тем не менее, проблема есть.
https://2appstudio.com/journey/
Вот с этого сайта не могу скачать ни 32-, ни 64-битную версию для Windows.
[image: вот, что я получаю в Google Chrome]
Тоже самое и в Firefox, примерно.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Программа уж больно понравилась. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: попробуй с VPN соеденением

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что «это напрямую не связано с программированием»

Comment: У меня скачивается без проблем.

Comment: Попробуйте на время загрузки отключить антивирус, иногда срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Настроить хром так, чтобы он не удалял подозрительные файлы самостоятельно: https://superuser.com/questions/387724/how-to-disable-download-scanning-protection-of-new-chrome-17
2. Выбрать сохранение скачанного файла в следующем запросе:

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего дело в провайдере или DNS. [Вот](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfD30Da0yWPDUqzNnaQeaGQW-VYoAUKW/view?usp=sharing) файл на Google Drive. В таких ситуациях можно найти бесплатный прокси(погуглить по ключевику `proxy list`) и [настроить](https://best-proxies.ru/kb/kak-nastroit-proksi-v-firefox/) подключение с его использованием в Firefox.